# how can I change marker options without using marker = new google.maps.Marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have found the function below which creates only one marker - which is what I want.
But how do I change the marker options e.g. html - without creating a new one?
i.e. the code below will move an existing marker using setPosition but what if I also want its html and title changed....

var marker;

```
function placeMarker(location) {
if ( marker ) {
marker.setPosition(location);
} else {
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  map: map
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html is the content of the infoWindow bound to the marker's 'click' event. There is an infoWindow.setContent() method.  I would extend the marker to hold the html content when you create it, then update it where you reset the position, title, etc.  Then you need to write you own 'click' event handler to use something against a single global infoWindow.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(marker.html);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
```

Comment: I think I've been a bit naive and just slavishly worked with the original code. So instead of infoBubble.setContent(marker.html); I could use any variable for the content as in var content = contents;
infoBubble.setContent(content);.....I think

Comment: Yup . that's sorted my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the properties of the marker object mostly have corresponding get and set methods, [as detailed in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)

For example, Title has a get_Title() method and a set_Title() method, which you can use like this...

```
myMarker.setTitle('my new title');
```

Comment: Thanks Baldy - that solves my title problem but I don't see an option for html ... or can I just create one e.g. marker.setHtml('stuff');

Comment: the documentation suggests there is no such property.  Where have you seen this property? or are you referring to an older version of google maps (such as v2) that may include this potentially deprecated property?

Comment: ah. I'm working with infoBubble which refers to the marker option html -  infoBubble.setContent(marker.html); and 'html' is basically the equivalent of the info window contentString. The 'html' is one of the marker options - marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: markercenter,
      map: map,
   shadow: shadow,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
   html:'<div id="bubbleNamez">'+markerName+'</div>',
   draggable: false,
      title:markerName
     });

Answer (score 1):

Maker is a MVCObject and this class have the **set** method

```
marker.set(property, New_Value);
```

If you want to change more than one property, you can use `setOptions` method